# Different theme behaviour on physical phone (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The default theme applied to my xamarin android project displays different on a physical phone than on an emulated phone.

I have not changed any style beside
some overrides for android.
As far as I am aware, the controls are shown and usable, only the colors are wrong.

I also have published the app via APK and installed it. So no debugger attached or anything, just plain installation. Same result though.

Emulated:
[image: Emulated Phone]

Physical:
[image]

This is my login View:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid Padding="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="teleport_foundation_logo.jpg"
                   Margin="0, 20, 0, 50" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                     VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding UsernameTitle}" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Username}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding PasswordTitle}" />
            <Entry IsPassword="True"
                   Text="{Binding Password}" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SaveUsername}" />
                <Label Text="Remember username" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowAdvanced}" />
                <Label Text="Advanced options"
                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowAdvanced}"
                  Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Server Address" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding ServerAddress}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
            
        </StackLayout>
        <Button VerticalOptions="Center" 
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My App.xaml:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3, 0, 0, 0" />
        </Style>
        <Color x:Key="Primary">#1976D2</Color>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffe6e6" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

And Accent Color override on Android (styles.xml):

```xml
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  <item name="colorAccent">#1976D2</item>
</style>
```

This is my first real xamarin project, so any input is appreciated!

Comment: **1)** There is no way to know what is wrong, unless you *add all relevant xaml and/or code* to question. **2)** What Android version (or API number) is the emulator? The physical device? **3)** Set the background color behind those controls to something very different. I often use HotPink. This will reveal if what is "not showing" is the same color as the background was.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the elements are drawn and usable, but textcolor, and the border of entries are the same color as the background color

Comment: Hence my question. If you change the background color, then do those details become visible? I'll **assume** your answer is "yes". Therefore, what could you add to which styles, to force those details to have the desired colors? [If changing background color makes the details appear, then it seems that default colors are not the same on different devices and/or API versions. Therefore the fix is to **explicitly declare** the desired colors. I was attempting to lead you through that thought process, so that you would realize what was happening, and therefore what fix was needed.]

Comment: Well your thought process is reliant on your knowledge. I can imagine that defining ever single color myself will solve this solution.
But my thought process leads me to the question, why there's a base theme, why the app works in an emulated environment, and so on.

Comment: Actually, my thought process was the one I went through when I first encountered this puzzle, which was between iOS and Android. Now that devices support theming at the OS level (e.g. dark theme vs light theme), it seems that the "problem" has spread. Xamarin Forms creates native controls. So the underlying question becomes: should Xamarin automatically specify all colors to a fixed default, or should it default to the OS's current theme? This could be argued either way, but the decision made by Xamarin devs was to allow the OS theme to be in control, except where app dev defines colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,

The system preferred theme overrides the different elements, hence why in emulated environment (Light Theme) the elements where rendered as expected and on physical phone (Dark Mode) not.

Since I wanted to have one style for all devices, the rather simple solution is adding following line in your Android Project `MainAcitity.cs`:

```cs
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```